# The group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \to S_9$ for this function.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

The group homomorphsim, $f$ : $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}  \to  S_9$ by $f((1,0)) = (3,6,7)(2,5,4,8)$ and $f((0,1)) = (1,7)(5,6,8,9)$

The question made by my lecturer required to find the $f((29,-7))$

Say $f(1,0) = a$, $f(0,1) = b$

I could easily find that by $f((29,-7)) = f(29(1,0) -7(0,1) ) = a^{29} b^{-7}$

Or an other method, Vice versa for the  case $f((29,-7))  = f(-7(0,1) + 29(1,0) ) = b^{-7}a^{29}$

If the $f$ is well defined  $f((29,-7)) = a^{29} b^{-7} =  b^{-7}a^{29}$, But When I checked it, the result was $a^{29} b^{-7} \neq  b^{-7}a^{29}$

So my conclusion is the $f$ is not well-defined. Hence this question is nonsense. Is my thought right?

Thank you.

Comment: Your mapping $f$ is not a homomorphism of groups and cannot be extended to a homomorphism. If $f$ is a homomorphism and $f(1,0)=a$, then $a^2=1$.

Comment: Perhaps the domain of $f$ should be $Z_{12} \times Z_{12}$?

Comment: @kabenyuk. Sorry for typo

Comment: @DerekHolt, there was a typo in my question. It is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: You are right, $f$ cannot be extended to a morphism of groups if $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$ do not commute... They are not even close to commuting, so it's a bit strange. Are you sure it was the symbol $×$ in $ℤ×ℤ$ and not $∗$?

Comment: @Idéophage. Yes It said Cartesian Product "X" not the "*"

Comment: Then correct the permutations, they should commutate. Otherwise this question is meaningless. You can see that yourself.